# pg-promise throwing read ECONNRESET errors

Tags: node.js, pg-promise

Using pg-promise 9.1.4 with Node 10 and 12 LTS on AWS Lambda accessing Aurora PG 9.6.12.

Monday afternoon we started seeing a sudden appearance of errors from pg-promise:  "read ECONNRESET" and "Client has encountered a connection error and is not queryable". There has also been a sudden increase in DB connections: (usually around 100, now 300+).

DB logs contain a lot of messages: "could not receive data from client: Connection reset by peer"

SELECT * FROM pg_stat_activity shows many old idle connections (ie: 2 hrs +).

To my knowledge, we did not make any recent changes to our configuration prior to this. It just seemed to come out of nowhere. We still have several old lambdas running on Node 6 and 8 that don't seem to be affected.

I have reached out to AWS Support, but haven't had a response yet. Is anyone else experiencing this, or have any idea how to handle this?